# $order->dateOrdered returns a string value the first time and DateTime after that. [Order got through event]

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I am using the Commerce 2 plugin and I am experiencing a very odd issue. Once an order is complete I want to use the dateOrdered property to create a csv which I send through a request endpoint. That worked fine.

BUT! Since recently (somewhere this month), on the first attempt to create and save the .csv, when calling `$order->dateOrdered->getTimestamp()` I get `dateOrdered` as a `string`.

On the second attempt to create and save the .csv I get `dateOrdered` as a `DateTime`.

The method which I am calling is the same so I think it has something to do wiht order statuses.

I tried to trace the problem in Commerce's `Order.php` class but I still have no clue why this occurs or what I am doing wrong.

Any help is more than welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occurring because the order was retrieved through the EVENT_AFTER_ORDER_PAID event. Therefore, the dateOrdered was still not processed (passed through mutations).

What we ended up doing is using `$event->sender` only to know what order we are looking for and then retrieve the order anew.

I hope this saves someone's life someday! I'll mark this question as solved in 2 days.